# Identifying the subject of a sentence

Tags: grammar-identification

> Dass bei diesem Interesse vor allem auch die Frage, welche Verhältnisse daran Schuld trugen, dass es ihm verwehrt blieb, dort aufzuwachsen, wo seine Vorfahren aufgewachsen waren, eine Rolle spielte, **hat nach dem Reportageband *Die fingierte Revolution. Bulgarien, eine exemplarische Geschichte (2006)* und dem Fernsehfilm *Vorwärts und nie vergessen – Ballade über bulgarische Helden (2007)* nun zu diesem monumentalen Roman geführt.**

Which is the subject of bolded sentence?

http://www.poetenladen.de/jacobsen-ilija-trojanow-macht-und-widerstand.htm

Comment: It hides in the part which is not bold ;-).

Answer (score 12):

The subclause *Dass bei diesem Interesse vor allem auch die Frage, (...) eine Rolle spielte* is the subject of the sentence. This is called *Subjektsatz* in German.

Subclauses can be subject or object of a sentence.

A simpler example:

> Dass diese Frage eine Rolle spielt, erscheint mir unglaubwürdig.

*Dass diese Frage eine Rolle spielt* is the subject.

An example for the same subclause as an object (*Objektsatz*):

> Ich glaube nicht, dass diese Frage eine Rolle spielt.

Comment: That a clause can be a sentence's subject or object is also a feature of English.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause#Argument_clauses

Comment: "Dass dies das Subjekt ist, ist klar."

Answer (score 4):

The subject is invisible. Let's take a much simpler sentence with the same construction:
*Dass die Sonne scheint, ist schön.*
You could make the subject visible by expanding the sentence:
*Die Tatsache, dass die Sonne scheint, ist schön.* (The fact, that the sun is shining, is nice). Die Tatsache / the fact is the subject. If you swith positions of main and subordinate clause, you could also say: *Es is schön, dass die Sonne scheint* (It is nice that the sun is shining). Here the Es / it is the subject.

In the same way, you could add an *Die Tatsache,* before *dass bei diesem Interview...*

Comment: "Die fingierte Revolution. Bulgarien, eine exemplarische Geschichte" and "Vorwärts und nie vergessen – Ballade über bulgarische Helden (2007)"  are Apposition of noun "dem Reportageband" and  "dem Fernsehfilm"respectively, Is it correct?

Comment: IMHO, *die Frage* is the subject in this difficult sentence.

Comment: No, *die Frage* is the subject of *spielte*.

Comment: @RHa in other words, *die Frage* is the subject of the *Subjektsatz,* which is the subject of the entire sentence.  Alternatively, the *Subjektsatz* (more generally in English an [argument clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause#Argument_clauses)) is the subject of *hat geführt.*